# Full text search filter on text score

Tags: mongodb

I have the following find query that retrieves results ordered by textScore, but how can I apply criteria to only return documents that have text score of greater than 1?

```
db.foods.find(
   { $text: { $search: "red blue green" } },
   { score: { $meta: "textScore" } }
).sort( { score: { $meta: "textScore" } } )
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use the **[aggregation framework](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/#aggregation-pipeline-operator-reference)** to get the documents that have a text score of greater than 1 by doing a **[`$match`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/#pipe._S_match)** pipeline operation which will match on either the term "red" or "blue" or "green", followed by a **[`$project`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/#pipe._S_project)** operator pipeline which projects the score fields, and then do another **`$match`** pipeline operattion to returns only those documents with a score greater than 1.0. The "textScore" **[metadata](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/meta/#behavior)** is available for projections, sorts, and conditions subsequent the **`$match`** stage that includes the **`$text`** operation:

```
db.foods.aggregate([
    { 
        "$match": { 
               "$text": { 
                     "$search": "red blue green" 
                } 
         } 
    },
    { 
         "$project": { 
               "_id": 0, 
               "score": { 
                     "$meta": "textScore" 
                } 
          } 
     },
     { 
          "$match": { 
                "score": { "$gt": 1.0 } 
           } 
     }
])
```